How Spring Validator helper method ValidationUtils works?
I am kind of new to Spring Validator and came through some educational code like this:
@Component("singerValidator")
public class SingerValidator implements Validator {
  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Singer.class.equals(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "firstName", "firstName.empty");
  }
}

When I ran this code myself I got error like this:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'firstName' of bean class \[com.example.spring.tutorial.demo.ch10.validators.SingerValidator\]: Bean property 'firstName' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:627)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:617)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:105)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:225)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(ValidationUtils.java:172)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(ValidationUtils.java:115)
at com.example.spring.tutorial.demo.ch10.validators.SingerValidator.validate(SingerValidator.java:18)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:89)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:56)
at com.example.spring.tutorial.demo.ch10.Demo.main(Demo.java:28)

Looks like it's complaining about SingerValidator doesn't have a getter for the firstName field(which is expected since this field is supposed to be on Singer class)?
So my question is how does ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty work if it doesn't take the target as its input?
How can I make this code work?
Am I missing something here?

This code is fine, the problem is your Demo.main code which doesn't pass in a Singer but a SingerValidator.

Please provide a [mre].
